# Batch > Extract part of a line in a txt file between same character

Tags: string, batch-file, character

I have a text file with one line. I need to extract every parts of the line separated by a character. Example:

```
1212123123!asdf asdf asdf asdf u!herd!TOTO!
```

I need to be able to echo every parts between `!` without `!` and display them

```
A:1212123123
B:asdf asdf asdf asdf u
C:herd
D:TOTO
```

I didn't find the solution in the KB

I tried that :

```
Set "String=1212123123!asdf asdf asdf asdf u!herd!TOTO!"

for /f "delims=2" %%f in (%String%) do set "%%f" (
    Set "Up2Sub=%String:*!=%"
    Set "SubStr=%Up2Sub:!="&:"%"
    echo %SubStr%
    )
```

But I get the result :

```
The system cannot find the file 1212123123!asdf.
asdf asdf asdf asdf u
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

As you appear to have shown no effort in coding this yourself, here's a complete two line batch file answer which shows no effort in return. It will not be modified by myself, should you change your question criteria, or are unable to make subsequent adjustments yourself.

```batch-file
@Set "Line="&Set /P "Line="<"SingleLine.txt"
@If Defined Line Echo %Line:!=&Echo=%&Pause
```

Comment: Hi Compo, Really sorry for that. Thank you.